What could cause a stain on the ceiling and should I be concerned?
I noticed a stain on my kitchen ceiling right above the sink. I don’t think it was there before. My first thought is water, but since there's a bedroom directly above, I don't think the stain could be caused by that. However, I can't figure out what else it might be. We do have a space heater that seems like it's right above where the stain is. Is it possible it’s caused by the space heater?


water leak above

Possible water pipes are passing through that area in the ceiling.

pop out the light and look

would you take an answer no, you should not be concerned seriously?

to test if it is wet, poke a needle in it, and if it goes in easy it is leak

@DIY75 thanks for the advice. I tried poking a needle over the spot. Overall seemed firm but there is a small slightly darker spot that gave a little bit. Still pretty firm but felt different than the rest.

maybe a leak in early stage

While a leak is the most likely cause, [that can come from anywhere above, run along parts of the building and drip there. Leaking in at a window and along the floor joist, for example] if there's no leak an alternate cause you won't like is that you have uninvited guests (of the rodent sort) nesting there.
Should be relatively easy to pull out the light fixture and have a look, in either case.

That's 99.9% sure to be a leak, from someplace.  Whether it's from a pipe, a roof leak, or coming in through the side, I really can't venture a guess.
The best way to tell is to cut out a small section of the sheetrock, 1'x1', and have a look, unless you have better access from the floor above that.
Your stain is very similar to what I have in the ceiling of my master bedroom in a vacation condo (see picture below).  In this case it was caused by a clogged AC condensate drain line from the unit above mine that caused the water to overflow the pan, run down along ceiling joists until the water detached and ripped onto the bedroom ceiling.  The leak was ~5 feet away from the AC unit.

This became really noticeable during the summer when the renters had the AC running full blast, pulling a lot moisture out of the air, and we could actually feel the wetness in the sheetrock.  The spot was damp to the touch when I took this picture.
